# Calling os_command.exec from an Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

I have used `os_command.exec` to send commands to the Linux shell. I am using Oracle 12c.

Here is an example code which works fine:

```
select os_command.exec('/home/smucha/app/smucha/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlldr userid=system/password control=/home/smucha/load_data.cmt')
from dual
```

I would like to run a similar command in a stored procedure. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried the following but it does not work. My procedure runs without errors but no records are loaded.

```
execute immediate 'select os_command.exec(''/home/smucha/app/smucha/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlldr userid=system/acorp56k control=/home/smucha/IZ/load_data.cmt'') from dual';
```

Comment: Presumably `os_command` is a Java stored procedure with PL/SQL funtion wrapper? What data type does that return? Showing at least the PL/SQL spec might be useful. (It may be [this one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf), so it returns an int?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is never executed. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#CJABDAAE):

> If *dynamic_sql_statement* is a SELECT statement, and you omit both *into_clause* and *bulk_collect_into_clause*, then *execute_immediate_statement* never executes.

Your `execute immdiate` doesn't have an `into` clause, so it's essentially ignored.

You don't need the query though, you can call the function directly:

```
procedure foo is
  result pls_integer; -- or whatever type your function actually returns
begin
  result := os_command.exec('/home/smucha/app/smucha/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlldr userid=system/password control=/home/smucha/load_data.cmt');
  -- do something with the result?
end foo;
```

As an aside, you might want to consider using an external table rather than a call out to SQL*Loader.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved my problem and everything works great!