# Running a Java procedure from an Oracle procedure by defining it as an Oracle procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

we using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

I've loaded the OS_COMMAND package in Oracle and I see it's all java.

The procedure I'm most interested in is the one that allows users to run a Linux command from with in an Oracle procedure. It's defined as the following: ex 1

```
  function exec(p_command in varchar2, p_stdin in blob) return number
  is language java name 'ExternalCall.exec(java.lang.String, oracle.sql.BLOB) return int';
```

How can I define this in an Oracle PL?SQL procedure OR a function in order for it to run as an Oracle function?

The only example I have is an Oracle procedure that defines a java method to use as an Oracle function. It's the following: ex 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SLDPROC.shell (p_command IN VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA 
NAME 'Host.executeCommand (java.lang.String)';
/
```

Which comes from the following java method: ex 3

```
 public class Host {
public static void executeCommand(String command) ...
...
```

So not having used java for a long time(20 yrs), how can I create a similar Oracle procedure to wrap a java procedure like the set_exec_in_shell procedure defined in the first example, ex 1?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to write a Java stored procedure that receives an operating system command as a string and executes that command. Is that correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling os\_command.exec from an Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291540/calling-os-command-exec-from-an-oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define this in an Oracle procedure in order for it to run as an Oracle function?

You do not need to "define" it as it is already a procedure within the `OS_COMMAND` package; just make sure the package is compiled and then call it directly from the function.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION your_function RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  OS_COMMAND.SET_EXEC_IN_SHELL();
  RETURN 1;
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried that. I'm getting an error telling me :"[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
3/3     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXEC'
3/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors" Could that be because the java function is actually overloaded with multiple versions of 'exec' and multiple version of parameters. Am I going to have to define a package that houses every combination of overloaded function in order to get this to work?